# how to handle two different vertical and horizontal lists

Tags: html, css

I have made two lists, one is horizontal and the other is vertical, each of them having different look.

how do I specify (a:link, a:visited, a:hover,a:active) properties for both of them separately?

**Top horizontal menu**

```
            <!DOCTYPE>
        <html>
        <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="d.css"/>

        <title></title>
        </head>

        <body>
        <ul id="topp">
            <li class="tl"><a href="#" class="ta"> Home </a></li>
            <li class="tl"><a href="#" class="ta"> New Products </a></li>
            <li class="tl"><a href="#" class="ta"> Specials </a></li>
            <li class="tl"><a href="#" class="ta"> Contact </a></li>
        </ul>

        </body>
        </html>
```

top horizontal menu css file

```
            @charset "utf-8";
        /* CSS Document */

        #container{
            border-style:solid;
            border-width:thin;
            background-color:green;
            height:100%;
        }
        .inner{
            border-style:solid;
            border-width:thin;
            background-color:#0C3;
            height:600px;
            width:90%;
            position:absolute;
            left:50px;
        }



        #head{
            background-color:#FF9;
            height:100px;
            width:80%;
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            bottom:550;
            left:0;
            right:0;
            margin:auto;

        }
        #topp{
            list-style-type:none;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            position:absolute;
            top:100;
            bottom:550;
            left:300;
            right:0;
            margin:auto;

        }
        .ta{ /*Top menu anchor*/
            display:block;
          width:100px;


        }
        .tl{ /*top menu list*/
            background-color:#3F6;
            border-style:solid;
            border-width:thin;
            float:left;
            text-align:center;
        }

         a:link,a:visited
        {
        display:block;
        font-weight:bold;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        background-color:#98bf21;
        width:120px;
        text-align:center;
        padding:4px;
        text-decoration:none;
        }

        a:hover,a:active
        {
        background-color:#FF9;
        color:#000;
        }
```

**Vertical Menu**

```
                <!DOCTYPE>
            <html>
            <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="leftm.css"/>

            <title></title>
            </head>

            <body>
            <div class="arrowgreen">
            <ul class="glossymenu">
            <li><a href="#" class="selected" title="Home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"  title="new products">new products</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="specials">specials</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>    
            </ul>
            </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

**vertical menu css file**

```
        @charset "utf-8";
    /* CSS Document */

    .arrowgreen{
        width: 180px; /*width of menu*/
        border-style: solid solid none solid;
        border-color: #94AA74;
        border-size: 1px;
        border-width: 1px;
    }

    .arrowgreen ul{
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .arrowgreen li a{
        font: bold 12px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        display: block;
        background: transparent url(media/arrowgreen.gif) 100% 0;
      height: 24px; /*Set to height of bg image- padding within link (ie: 32px - 4px - 4px)*/
        padding: 4px 0 4px 10px;
        line-height: 24px; /*Set line-height of bg image- padding within link (ie: 32px - 4px - 4px)*/
        text-decoration: none;
    }   

    .arrowgreen li a:link, .arrowgreen li a:visited {
        color: #5E7830;
    }

    .arrowgreen li a:hover{
        color: #26370A;
        background-position: 100% -32px;
    }


    /*.arrowgreen li a.selected{
        color: #26370A;
        background-position: 100% -64px;
    }
    */
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just prefix the element specifiers with a preceding type/class specifier:

```
.someClass a:link { }
.someOtherClass a:link { }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should add a class or an id to every list **container**:

```
<ul class="list-1">
  <li><a href="#">Foo</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bar</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Baz</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="list-2">
  <li><a href="#">Foo</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bar</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Baz</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then you can use the parent selector in CSS like this:

```
.list-1 a:link {color: red;}      /* unvisited link */
.list-1 a:visited {color: orange;}  /* visited link */
.list-1 a:hover {color: yellow;}  /* mouse over link */
.list-1 a:active {color: pink;}  /* selected link */

.list-2 a:link {color: blue;}      /* unvisited link */
.list-2 a:visited {color: violet;}  /* visited link */
.list-2 a:hover {color: lightblue;}  /* mouse over link */
.list-2 a:active {color: purple;}  /* selected link */
```

The answer would be more precise if you shared actual code via http://jsbin.com .

Comment: Worth a mention that ID(#ID) must be unique and that a class can be used multiple times. Therefore if it is only one element that needs specific styling use ID and if there are multiple elements that require the same styling then use a class (.class) .

Comment: @jezzipin Incorrect. `id` should _never_ be used to specify styling. Run it through a CSS validator, it's illegal.

Comment: Also, IDs have higher specificity than classes so instead of using chained classes to reference a particular element you should use the #ID tag as it is faster and speeds up load time. Therefore it's more practical in real world use than some useless CSS validator.